# ScrollViewer ZoomMode on touch screen

Tags: c#, uwp, pinchzoom

My code :

```
 <ScrollViewer IsZoomChainingEnabled="True" IsZoomInertiaEnabled="True"  ZoomMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
<Grid>
                   <Rectangle Name="touchRectangle"
               Height="100" Width="200" Fill="Blue"/>
                    </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

When on PC, this code works perfectly i mean when i point at any area of grid and use CTRL+Scroll it will zoom at my pointer but on touch screen when i use pinch zoom it just zoom at one area only not where my finger is pinching. Any ideas guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem, just add `ManipulationMode="System"`, ScrollViewer will handle this